# How to query mongoose by property that is and array item

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PictureSchema = new Schema({
    listId: { type: Array, required: true },
    thumb: { type: String, required: true },
    large: { type: String, required: true }
});

var Picture = module.exports = mongoose.model('Picture', PictureSchema);
```

I am trying to update instances of this model in my router by looking up a Picture via the "listId" property. Like this:

```
app.put('/pictures/append', function(req, res) {
  var targetListId = req.body.targetListId
    , currentListId = req.body.currentListId;

  Picture
    .find({ listId: currentListId }, function (err, picture) {
      console.log('found pic', picture);
      picture.listId.push(targetListId);
      picture.save(function(err, pic) {
        console.log('pic SAVED', pic);
      });
    });
});
```

"currentListId" is a string, and listId is an array of currentListId's. Maybe this isn't the correct way to query a a property that is an array? 
I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

On the line:

```
picture.listId.push(targetListId);
```

But when I look up the picture models in mongo, they DO have listId arrays and some DO contain the item "currentListId" that I am using for my query.

I tried using $elemMatch and $in but I don't know if I was using them correctly. 
Any idea if I am just writing my query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an `Array` typed field in your schema is equivalent to `Mixed` which tells Mongoose that field could contain anything.  Instead, change your schema to something like this:

```
var PictureSchema = new Schema({
    listId: [String],
    thumb: { type: String, required: true },
    large: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed part of my problem. I also needed to tweak my routers update code like so: `.update({ listId: { $in: [currentListId] } }, {$push: {'listId' : targetListId } }, { multi: true }, function (err, data) { console.log('Updated', data); });`

Comment: @nicki9knuckles Great, and welcome to SO.  If your question is resolved, you can click the check mark to the left of the answer.